# Android Library answer wait

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a library that deals with smart cards. It has an asynchronous function that sends me an answer when it is finished. Well I'm calling this function in main UI thread. I have provided to that library a handler class ( Message Handler). My question is: I need to stop my  main thread and wait for answer from that function, after this I need to do another step. How it can be done?

I've tried with CountDownLatch - but when I call await() function I never get the answer from library ( I think that library is calling my answer handler class in ui thread, so it also enter in infinite wait).

Comment: I don't suggest you stopping UIThread, this will cause an ANR and Android will kill your app. Did you check [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

Comment: Why would a user want its application' s main thread to stop? See this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Comment: Well it is not important now, I will call this function in another thread... The question is how to wait until library will answer me...